# User potentionaly selling their profile page as an advert?

Tags: support, advertising

I came across [this today](https://askubuntu.com/users/237592/alex) and it very much gives the impression the user wants to sell their profile page as an advertising space.

As I have never come across this before, though I am sure it happens,I just wanted to ask, is this OK? I doubt SE would allow this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't serious. :)

The [content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) mentions affiliate marketing:

> Spam. Users that do not publish meaningful content, use deceptive means to generate revenue or traffic, **or whose primary purpose is affiliate marketing**, will be suspended.

Wether this rule applies depends on the specific case. The user profile you linked certainly doesn't violate it.

Disclaimer: I am just some guy, and this is the way I read the content policy. If you have any concerns that a user is violating any of the rules, [contact Stack Exchange](http://meta.askubuntu.com/contact) and they'll take care of it.

See also [Rules for Profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles) on Meta SE and a [What to do when a user's profile is advertising websites that are 'off-topic'](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/what-to-do-when-a-users-profile-is-advertising-websites-that-are-off-topic) on Gaming.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the users `primary purpose is affiliate marketing` at all, they do answer questions too. I will just let it go if you guys don't think it is a big deal.